# Refused to execute script from 'package location' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: jquery, reactjs, jquery-ui

Am trying to implement noConflicts in JQuery in a React application, I am trying to do this for whole application. I have added the below script in my index.html but am getting the below error in console.
[I have attached my package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZIld.png)

**Script I have added:**
`<script type="application/javascript" src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"> jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>`

**Error I am Getting**
`*Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost/delivery/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.*`

**Things I have tried**

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"> jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>`